# Play audio using online compiler

Tags: python, audio, compilation

I am working on a program, and I want to be able to play a mp3 file (preferably, though other files could work). The catch is that, unfortunately, I'm using an online compiler ([repl.it](http://repl.it)), and I can't use a desktop compiler. In other words, I can't use pyglet, or really any package not part of the standard ones. I've looked all over stack exchange, google, and beyond, but I can't seem to find anything. I don't need to edit the file, just play it.

I am using chrome as my browser, and the computer I'm using is a chromebook.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could mention what online compiler you're using, and the overall environment?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, of course, I'm using [repl.it](https://repl.it) as the compiler. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the overall environment; I'm somewhat new. I will update my question with the compiler.

Comment: I think he's referring to what operating system, web browser, etc. you are using

Comment: @downshift, okay, thank you. I've updated my question with that information.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I added my operating system and web browser to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could install a library for audio playback on the online REPL, wouldn't the sound be played back somewhere in the racks of a data center instead of your computer at home?

AFAIK, the only currently feasible solution to this problem is to use an online service that allows HTML output and to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag to play back the desired sound on your local computer via your browser. I prefer to use [Jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter.org/) for that.

IPython provides [IPython.display.Audio](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Audio) which turns a Python buffer, a `bytes` object or a NumPy array into an `<audio>` tag. You can try this immediately at https://try.jupyter.org/. Note that this embeds the raw audio data into the notebook, making it quite large.

I normally prefer to save the resulting audio data to a sound file (e.g. a WAV file) and manually create an `<audio>` tag for it within a Markdown cell. You can of course also do this on https://try.jupyter.org/.

If you want to share your results with others, you can for example use [Binder](http://mybinder.org/). Here is an example of a [Jupyter notebook using HTML5 `<audio>` elements running interactively on Binder](http://mybinder.org/repo/spatialaudio/communication-acoustics-exercises/notebooks/brir-solutions.ipynb). You can even install custom libraries on your Binder, see for example [my Dockerfile](https://github.com/spatialaudio/communication-acoustics-exercises/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: Thank you, this is impressively helpful.